# What is the 2.8 shortcut for "Operator Search" on Mac?

Tags: workflow, shortcut

I would like to know what key or key combination opens the search field in Blender 2.8 on a Mac. Can anyone answer this? "F3" does not do it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have to hold down function (fn) then hit f3.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for me. I am on a Mac, but using an external Windows-like (German) keyboard. None of the function keys are actually recognized, even when trying to manually map them.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold down <kbd>fn</kbd> and then hit <kbd>F3</kbd>.

If this is not working for you maybe you can change your hotkey for that.
You can read about Keymap editor in the link below. The Keymap editor lets you change the default hotkeys. You can change keymaps for each of Blender’s editors.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/keymap.html

This thread may also be helpful:

[how do you change the keyboard shortcuts in blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148936/how-do-you-change-the-keyboard-shortcuts-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: You might want to *explain how* to change the shortcut *in detail*, otherwise your answer is just a copy of the other answer already given one year ago.

Comment: I added a link for that.

Comment: And how to change the shortcut to call "operator search"?

Answer (score 0):

I kept right click select keymap ... So for me it is still **Spacebar**