# how do you change the keyboard shortcuts in blender 2.8?

Tags: shortcut

I'm trying to find the search short cut and f3 isn't working on my computer so I'd like to change it to another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the setting panel,
choose **keymap**
and type `search` in the keymap searching bar

change the key for it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the search hotkey is available, like all of the shortcuts, in the "keymap" section of the user preferences. You  can change any shortcut there.